# How to interpret "true value" being outside of the 90% confidence interval a certain percentage of the time for a bayesian regression model

Tags: regression, bayesian, confidence-interval, uncertainty

I have developed a bayesian regression model that predicts a mu and sigma of a continuous variable. Lets say the model was trained on 10,000 samples, and validated on 1000 unseen test samples. Afterwards, I calculated for each of the 1000 predicted samples if the 90% confidence interval (calculated using the predicted mu and sigma for each sample) contained the "true" test value.

Here are hypothetical results for three variables:
Variable #1: 90% CI contains true test value 80% of the time (800 out of the 1000 test samples).
Variable #2: 90% CI contains true test value 60% of the time (600 out of the 1000 test samples).
Variable #3: 90% CI contains true test value 95% of the time (950 out of the 1000 test samples).

Can someone help me understand how to interpret these results? How can I explain my confidence/uncertainty in the model in regards to the three variables?

Comment: Do you mean a credible interval?

Comment: Because you’re talking about Bayesian LR, I figured I should check: do you mean confidence interval, or do you actually mean credible interval?

Comment: I guess from what I understand, you guys are right in that it is a credible interval in regards to bayesian LR, in that for each sample, a predicted distribution given by mu and sigma (the posterior) gives the range containing a particular percentage of probable values. Am i thinking of this correctly?

Comment: A confidence interval is any function where the interval covers the parameter at least some minimum specified percentage of the time upon infinite repetition.  A Bayesian credible set can be made up of disjoint intervals.  It is any region of the posterior distribution that has the specified mass.  Usually, the highest density region is used because it has a number of optimality-related properties, however, under some loss functions that would not be the choice made.

Comment: Credible intervals are conditioned on the actual observations.  Confidence intervals tend to be derived from estimators.  For example, if you had two sets of observations with the same sample average and standard deviation, then you would get the same confidence interval for both.  There are definitely circumstances where that does not hold true for the Bayesian intervals.

Comment: So if those are credible intervals I have calculated, what does it mean for my confidence in the model output if the interval contains the true value less than 90% of the time as in variables 1 and 2. And if more than 90% as in variable 3? Thanks.